# В честь Дня Победы или в честь Победы?

Tags: фразеология

Прошли юбилейные торжества в честь Дня Победы во Второй мировой войне.

Или правильно:

Прошли юбилейные торжества в честь Победы во Второй мировой войне.

Василий Аксенов. Таинственная страсть 
Один мне вроде намекал на приеме в честь Дня независимости: "Ты что, Антон, чокнулся?"

Марк Дейч. Зеленый терроризм (2003) // «Московский комсомолец», 2003.01.15
9 мая 2002 г. в городе Каспийске (Дагестан) во время праздничного шествия в честь Дня Победы прогремел мощный взрыв.

Comment: Точно во **Второй мировой**? День победы - он у нас в **Великой отечественной**, а на Западе, где таки во Второй Мировой его называют днем победы над нацизмом. Вторая мировая кончилась победой над Японией. Это признают даже отечественные историографы.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Возможны оба варианта, но первый более конкретно указывает на день торжеств. Во втором случае могут подразумеваться и более длительные мероприятия.

Более точно нейтральное "по случаю дня", но обычно подразумевается "в честь события, в юбилейный или просто праздничный день", поэтому можно коротко сказать "в честь дня".

Comment: А вам само по себе это "в честь Дня" ухо не режет? Какая у дня честь?

Comment: Про несоответствие даты и названия уже сказал.

Comment: "Особенностей" названия просто не заметил (по невниманию - увлёкся формой, о которой вопрос). "В честь Дня...(праздника с таким названием)" - здесь буквальный смысл неточен, как  я уже сказал, но такое условное выражение (салют или торжества "в честь праздника" - это почитаемый праздник, его принято отмечать торжественно) получило распространение и я считаю его допустимым.

Comment: Не все, что получило распространение, надо принимать как данность.

Comment: Я сам так не говорю, но со стороны отношусь к этому терпимее, чем к некоторым другим "распространённостям" :) .

Answer (score 1):

Очень спорный случай. Скорее всего оба варианта следует признать стилистически неправильными.

Вообще "мероприятия в честь дня Победы" вызывает ощущение какой-то тавтологии и нелогичности. Какая честь может быть у "Дня"? Тарабарщина какая-то. И потом получается, что "День Победы" (мероприятие такое) заслуживает чествования, а не Победа. Хотя у нас многое сместилось...

"Юбилейное заседание в честь десятой годовщины предыдущего заседания по тому же случаю".

Думаю, беспроигрышным решением будет воспользоваться другими вариантами.

**Юбилейные торжества по случаю Дня Победы.**
**Юбилейные торжества в ознаменование 70-й годовщины Победы.**
И т.д.

А "честь" оставим людям. В исключительных случаях - особым символам (честь мундира).

(+)

doom, точно во **Второй мировой**? День Победы - он у нас в **Великой Отечественной**, а на Западе, где таки во "Второй мировой", его называют днем победы над нацизмом. "Вторая мировая" кончилась победой над Японией. Это признают даже отечественные историографы.

Comment: Речь о мероприятиях в Монголии: День Победы во Второй мировой войне. На некоторых сайтах избегают называть _Великая Отечественная война_,  если речь идет о войне советского народа. И даже о Дне Победы в Великой Отечественной войне пишут: День Победы во Второй мировой войне.                                                                                                                           _игнорировать 70-летие советской Победы над нацистами_;  _в честь 70-й годовщины победы во Второй мировой войне_ - так пишут на BBC.

Comment: Радио Свобода: В США и в большинстве стран Европы сегодня отмечают День победы во Второй мировой войне.

Comment: Но тут же через два абзаца: Ранее в польском городе Гданьск прошла церемония, посвященная 70-летию победы над нацистской Германией.

Comment: И далее - На Украине в этом году впервые День победы отмечается 8 мая.

Comment: сам День Победы на Украине теперь называется День победы над нацизмом.

Comment: В Википедии: День Победы в Европе (V-E Day, или Victory in Europe Day) — праздник, во время которого Советский Союз, США, Великобритания и большинство стран Западной Европы отмечают День Победы во Второй мировой войне.

Comment: День Побе́ды над Япо́нией или День Победы в Ти́хом океа́не (англ. Victory over Japan Day, Victory in the Pacific Day, VJ Day, VP Day) — праздник, который отмечается 14 августа в Великобритании и 2 сентября в США.

Comment: В Европе в пятницу 8 мая празднуют окончание Второй мировой войны. Эту дату там называют Днем памяти и примирения.

Comment: Верховная Рада установила 8 мая День памяти и примирения в Украине в честь всех жертв Второй мировой войны.  В то же время парламент решил оставить 9 мая Днем победы над нацизмом во Второй мировой войне, который является государственным праздником.

Comment: Дни памяти и примирения  посвящены памяти жертв Второй мировой войны. Отмечаются ежегодно 8 мая и 9 мая, начиная с 2005 года. Провозглашены Генеральной Ассамблеей ООН в резолюции, посвящённой празднованию шестидесятилетия окончания Второй мировой войны (Резолюция № A/RES/59/26 — Празднование шестидесятой годовщины окончания второй мировой войны — от 22 ноября 2004 года).

Comment: Предлагается государствам - членам ООН, неправительственным организациям, частным лицам, кроме празднования своих Дней Победы и Освобождения, ежегодно также отмечать один или оба эти дня (8 и 9 мая) как дань памяти всем жертвам Второй мировой войны.

Answer (score -2):

Победу праздновали 9 мая 1945 года, поэтому спустя 70 лет правильно будет: "Прошли юбилейные торжества в честь Дня Победы во Второй мировой войне."

Comment: После 9 мая 1945 г. Вторая мировая война продолжалась ещё около 4-х месяцев. Поэтому, предложенный вами вариант никак не правильный.

Comment: Донесите эту "правду" до народов и правительств всех стран! Оказывается праздновать День победы 9 мая -это неправильно! )))

Comment: 9 мая отмечают День Победы в Великой Отечественной войне, Окончание II Мировой отмечают 2 сентября.